# Issues verifying trust chain with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I read another questions about this topic but they didn't help me.

I have a **root CA** self-signed.

```
[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in rootca.cer -noout -subject
subject= /O=org/CN=ROOT CA

[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in rootca.cer -noout -issuer
issuer= /O=org/CN=ROOT CA
```

I have an **intermediate CA** signed by the root CA.

```
[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in intermediateca.cer -noout -subject
subject= /O=org/CN=INTERMEDIATE CA

[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in intermediateca.cer -noout -noout -issuer
issuer= /O=org/CN=ROOT CA
```

I also have the **final certificate** signed by intermediate CA.

```
[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in finalcert -noout -subject
subject= blabla

[ubuntu@user]$ openssl x509 -in finalcert -noout -noout -issuer
issuer= /O=org/CN=INTERMEDIATE CA
```

This is the **verify process** that I followed.

```
[ubuntu@user]$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.cer  intermediateca.cer
intermediateca.cer: OK

[ubuntu@user]$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.cer  -untrusted intermediateca.cer  finalcert.cer
finalcert.cer: blabla
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Why can't I verify the final cert correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: The process should be the correct one. But there might be something wrong with the certificates and just showing subject and issuer is not sufficient to find out where the problem is. Please provide the actual certificates .

Comment: Also the version of OpenSSL used, because some details of chain build/verify have changed over the years. FYI you can display multiple fields in one command: `openssl x509 -in file -noout -subject -issuer`

Comment: Thank you both for the help. The issue was that, as you said, issuer and subject is not the only thing to check in certificates. Public key of intermediate CA has changed after the final cert was signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just noticed that public key of intermediateca.cer has been changed after final cert was signed. This is why the verification returns an error.

This can be checked with the hash of public keys in intermediante and final certs. The hashes are stored in Subject Key Identifier and Authority Key Identifier keys.